# Monaco editor how to highlight function argument name

Tags: regex, highlight, monaco-editor

I want highlight the argument name title and type in Monaco editor(it is a language write myself)

```
myfunc(1, title ="aab", type="int")
```

I add this regex. it not work(test url https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/monarch.html, select python language)

```
argname:[
        [/(?<=[(,])\s*([a-z]+)\s*(?=\=)/g,'argname']
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to do this in React is:

```
      editorRef.current.editor.createDecorationsCollection([
        {
          range: new editorRef.current.monaco.Range(1, 7, 1, 11), // 1 is line, 7-11 is column
          options: {
            className: "bg-green-800 border border-green-200 rounded-md",
            inlineClassName: `px-0.5`,
            hoverMessage: { value: "HERE WE GO" },
          },
        },
      ]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Colors are defined by themes in monaco-editor. Define your own theme like demonstrated in [the playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#customizing-the-appearence-exposed-colors).

Comment: i mean highlight  argument name  with a color